# Назван был Вавилоном, то есть "смешением". Нужны ли кавычки?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, переводы, кавычки, пояснительная

Пояснительная конструкция содержит не простое пояснение, а перевод на русский язык иностранного слова. Надо ли это как-то оформить: кавычками или сопутствующими словами: то есть по-русски "смешением"?

Comment: См. ответ @Людмила на похожий вопрос: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/437092/%d0%a1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba-%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b8

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то жители того города, который мы называем Вавилоном, назвали его в честь бога (в переводе на русский - "Врата Бога").

Есть библейская трактовка названия Вавилон, которая связывает это название со словом *смешение*, так как в первоисточнике эти слова похожи (Бабель и бильбуль), и (ретроспективно) из-за того, что бог смешал там языки. Но я не уверен, что где-то сказано, что название этого города переводится как "смешение". Поэтому я заменил "то есть" на более мягкое "что означает". По-моему, так и правильней и звучит лучше, когда "заковыченное" слово стоит в именительном подеже.

Думаю, верными будет такой вариант:

**Назван был Вавилоном, что означает “смешение”.**

См. [ответ Людмилы на похожий вопрос](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/437092/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8).