# Слово "апостол" — греческое, означает — посланник. Нужны ли кавычки?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, кавычки

Вопрос только о кавычках, без изменения структуры предложений:

- *Слово "апостол" — греческое, означает — "посланник".* // *Слово "апостол" — греческое, означает — посланник.*
- *"Евангелие" — слово греческое, по-русски — "благая или радостная весть".* // *Евангелие — слово греческое, по-русски — "благая или радостная весть".*
- *Андрей впоследствии стал называться "Первозванным" // Андрей впоследствии стал называться Первозванным.* (речь об апостоле Андрее Первозванном).
- *Именно тогда святитель получил прозвание «Златоуст» // Именно тогда святитель получил прозвание Златоуст*. (речь об Иоанне Златоусте).
- *Город стал называться Вавилоном, то есть "смешением" // Город стал называться Вавилоном, то есть смешением.*

Может, разница непринципиальна? Правила на эти случаи не нашла. Пункты §128 из Розенталя **"Слова, употребляемые в необычном, условном, ироническом значении"** сюда не подходят.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, верными будут такие варианты:

Слово апостол — греческое, означает "посланник".

Евангелие — слово греческое, по-русски — "благая или радостная весть".

Андрей впоследствии стал называться Первозванным. (речь об апостоле Андрее Первозванном)

Именно тогда святитель получил прозвание Златоуст. (речь об Иоанне Златоусте)

Город стал называться Вавилоном, что означает "смешение"( или то есть "смешение")