# Курсив (ли), кавычки (ли), тире (ли) и прочая пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация

> До техники boun fresco, что означает хорошая фреска или (если говорить
>   о смысле) – фреска в нашем современном понимании, ещё далеко.

Что делать?

Я рисую:

*До техники **boun fresco,** что означает **хорошая фреска**, или (если говорить о смысле) фреска в нашем современном понимании, ещё далеко.*

Я не имею права курсивить от себя - в тексте много авторского курсива.

Перед *или* запятая нужна ли? Осторожно не вмешиваюсь.

И как же ж жить?! О_о

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагаю один из следующих вариантов:

До техники **boun fresco**, что означает "хорошая фреска", или просто фреска (в нашем современном понимании), ещё далеко.

До техники **boun fresco**, что означает "хорошая фреска", или "фреска" в нашем современном понимании, ещё далеко.

В любом случае я считаю, что вставка "(если говорить о смысле)" избыточна и не очень хорошо вписывается в стиль автора. Неужели это уточнение помогает восприятию текста или имеет стилистическую ценность?

Comment: Про избыточность поддерживаю, просто побоялся заходить так далеко :))

Answer (score 1):

Очень тяжелое для чтения и понимания предложение. Вариант правки:

**До техники boun fresco (что означает "хорошая фреска", или — если говорить о смысле – (просто) "фреска" в нашем современном понимании) ещё далеко.**

О постановке кавычек см. ответ Людмилы: [Слово "апостол" — греческое, означает — посланник. Нужны ли кавычки?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/437092/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8)